# get attribute containing a certain string of a named tuple python

Tags: python, namedtuple

is it possible to get the first argument that contain a certain string in a named tuple such has:

```
import collections

data_line = collections.namedtuple('ex', 'a_1 b_1 a_2')
data = data_line(a_1=10, b_1=11, a_2=10)

getattr(data, 'a_2')
```

I would like to get the first argument that contain the string 'a', something like:

```
getattr(data, contains('a'))
```

any pythonic way to acheive this? thanks!

Comment: You can't just put them in a list and slice the list: `[getattr(data, x) for x in data._fields if x.startswith('a')][0]`? Or `getattr(data, data._fields[0])`.

Comment: that would work! thank! you can post is as answer if you want!

Comment: Please see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it done by accessing the fields of the `namedtuple` and slicing the output to get your desired result:

Either:

```
[getattr(data, x) for x in data._fields if x.startswith('a')][0]
```

Or:

```
getattr(data, [x for x in data._fields if x.startswith('a')][0])
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what you want exactly but you can try something like this:

```
def contains(val):
    if val.startswith('a'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
for a in filter(contains, data._fields):
    getattr(data, a)
```

and you may want to have a list of a's:

```
a_list = list(filter(contains, data._fields))
```